# Value of binded variable changes it self when clicked on label element

Tags: angular

Here is my code:

```html
<input id="uploadFile" #inputFile type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (change)="onFileSelect($event, uploadDocumentTypeId)" />

<label for="uploadFile"  (click)="test(uploadDocumentTypeId)" class="job-btn btn btn-outline-primary small-width">Select</label>
```

And in the .ts file, both functions logs the value like this:

```js
onFileSelect(e: any, n: number) {
 console.log('typeId = ',this.uploadDocumentTypeId);
 console.log('n = ', n);
}

test(n: number){
 console.log("clicked", n);
}
```

The problem is that , the value of uploadDocumentTypeId is correct in the test method, but its different in the onFileSelect method. I cant find the reason, why this value is being changed.

Console log is as follows:

- clicked 1
- typeId =  3
- n =  3
- clicked 2
- typeId =  3
- n =  3
- clicked 3
- typeId =  3
- n =  3

P.S input element had a display:none class to always show the label instead but i have removed it here to test it.

Expected/required console log:

- clicked 1
- typeId =  1
- n =  1
- clicked 2
- typeId =  2
- n =  2
- clicked 3
- typeId =  3
- n =  3

It works fine, if i remove the label element completely from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Save the number in an attribute first and then use it.

```
export class Bla {
    private documentTypeId: number;

    onFileSelect(e: any, n: number) {
        console.log('typeId = ',this.uploadDocumentTypeId);
        console.log('n = ', n);
        this.documentTypeId = n;
    }

    test(){
        console.log("clicked", this.documentTypeId);
    }

}
```

And remove the test() parameter call

Comment: The property is sent to the component from another component, so i have already declared it like this. 

 @Input() uploadDocumentTypeId: number;

And unfortunatly , it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i finally figured out what i was doing wrong here. The above written code was written in a component which was used multiple times on the same page. Since the input(file) was hidden, and a label was used to display a good design. The label was unable to bind it self with the correct instance of the input(file) button.

When i removed the label, and styled in the input(file) button, the problem was solved.